# How can I filter out certain branches from git log?

Tags: git, branch, git-log, revision-history

I want to filter out certain branches (such as those matching `origin/build_*` for example) from my git log.

I've looked high and low and come across some great resources ([this one for example](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-log/filtering-the-commit-history)) but I still can't figure out how to do this.

From the documentation it looks like I should be able to do something like:

`git log --exclude=origin/build_* --branches`

but it doesn't work.

Comment: Try wrapping single quotes around your argument to `--exclude`, i.e. `git log --exclude='origin/build_*' --branches`. If that works I'll add a proper answer explaining why :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I needed was to filter on *remotes*, not branches:

`--exclude=origin/build_* --remotes`

Works great!